# Issues regarding IR sensor controlled car

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm here regarding the issue I'm having building my project which is IR sensor controlled car with a LCD screen. I have built only 2 projects before this one that I have coded and designed their circuits, hence, I'm fairly new to all this. I expected this car to go forward, turn left & right, and to stop. I first used the code to identify the key code of my IR remote for the buttons I want to use to control my project, then I wrote the code given below. But, whenever I use the buttons I have programmed, the project respond only once to the IR remote and then freezes and continues on. Suppose, If I click the button which I have programmed it to go forward, it starts going forward, but then it stops responding to other buttons. I've tried using higher voltage and current batter but that doesn't seem to help.

Here is the code:

```
// Setting up LCD Display Here.

#include<LiquidCrystal.h>

int RS = 13;
int E = 12;
int D4 = 11;
int D5 = 10;
int D6 = 6;
int D7 = 2;

LiquidCrystal lcd(RS,E,D4,D5,D6,D7);

// Setting up IR reciver sensor here.

#include<IRremote.h>

int IR_Reciver_Pin = A5;
IRrecv irrecv(IR_Reciver_Pin);
decode_results results;

// Setting up DC motor pins. 

/* Motor A connections */

int enA = 9;
int in1 = 8;
int in2 = 7;

/* Motor B connections */

int enB = 3;
int in3 = 5;
int in4 = 4;

void setup() {

  // Initiating LCD display here.

  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.print("Welcome!");

  // Initiating IR reciver sensor here.

  irrecv.enableIRIn();

  // Initiating Serial Monitor.

  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Initiating DC motors.

  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);

  // Turning motors off - Initial state
  
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
  
}

void loop() {

  // Reading IR remote value.
  
  if(irrecv.decode(&results)) 
    {
     int value = results.value;
     Serial.print(F("CODE: "));
     Serial.println(results.value);
     irrecv.resume();              
    }

  // Code for providing 5V to L293D H-Brigde.

  analogWrite(enA, 255);
  analogWrite(enB, 255);

  // Code for going forward.   

  if(results.value==3772778233)
    {
     lcd.clear();
     lcd.print(F("Rolling forward"));
     lcd.setCursor(0,2);
     lcd.print(F("captain!"));
     digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
     digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
     digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
     digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
    }

  // Code for turning right.

  if(results.value==3772794553)
     {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print(F("Turning towards"));
      lcd.setCursor(0,2);
      lcd.print(F("right."));
      digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
     }

  // Code for turning left.  

  if(results.value==3772819033)
     {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print(F("Turning towards"));
      lcd.setCursor(0,2);
      lcd.print(F("left."));
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW);  
     }

  // Code for stoping.

  if(results.value==3772782313)
     {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print(F("Halting captain!"));
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW); 
     }
}
```

[This is the circuit diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC5gE.png)

Comment: There can be hw issue, not sw. Try control motors by serial line. If works OK, check IR library code.

Comment: Please post this question on one of the hardware-related community pages.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I would say that the problem is that your if statments in loop should be nested inside : `if(irrecv.decode(&results)){}`

So, your loop should look something like this:

```
void loop() {

  analogWrite(enA, 255);
  analogWrite(enB, 255);

  while(!(irrecv.decode(&results))); //It waits until no button is pressed
  if(irrecv.decode(&results)) 
  {
     int value = results.value;
     Serial.print(F("CODE: "));
     Serial.println(results.value);
                   

  // Code for going forward.   

        if(results.value==3772778233)
            {
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.print(F("Rolling forward"));
            lcd.setCursor(0,2);
            lcd.print(F("captain!"));
            digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
            digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
            }

        // Code for turning right.

        if(results.value==3772794553)
            {
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.print(F("Turning towards"));
            lcd.setCursor(0,2);
            lcd.print(F("right."));
            digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
            digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
            digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
            }

        // Code for turning left.  

        if(results.value==3772819033)
            {
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.print(F("Turning towards"));
            lcd.setCursor(0,2);
            lcd.print(F("left."));
            digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
            digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
            digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(in4, LOW);  
            }

        // Code for stoping.

        if(results.value==3772782313)
            {
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.print(F("Halting captain!"));
            digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
            digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
            digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
            digitalWrite(in4, LOW); 
            }
        irrecv.resume();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input and taking your time to respond. Will definitely try this out.